# How to use a conditional test to exit a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First a little about the program itself:

- A conditional test begins the while loop (I have to use a conditional test to begin and end the loop, No flags and no break statements)
- Asks for users age (user input)
- Depending on the user input, it prints out different answers

My problem is that I want the program to end if the user input is 'quit'. The user input will besides 'quit' always be an int, because the program checks the users age.

This is my code:

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter your age to see the price for a ticket. \nEnter 'quit' when done: "

age = ""

while age != "quit":
    age = input(prompt)
    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free.")
    elif age > 3 and age < 12:
        print("Ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Ticket is $15")
```

This is the error i get when i put 'quit' as the input:

```
Please enter your age to see the price for a ticket.  Enter 'quit' when done: quit 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "while_loops.py", line 60, in <module>
    age = int(age) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
```

Many thanks in advance for your time and effort! Best regards HWG.

Comment: `raw_input` is py2 only.

Comment: You can chain comparisons: `3 < age < 12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `quit` before you try to convert to `int`. Run in an infinite loop and break out of it when you read the input `quit`.

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter your age to see the price for a ticket. \nEnter 'quit' when done: "

while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == "quit":
        break
    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free.")
    elif age > 3 and age < 12:
        print("Ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Ticket is $15")
```

Alternative which meet added criteria

> not use 'break' or a variable as a flag

Using an exception

```
while ageStr != "quit":
    ageStr = input(prompt)

    try:
        age = int(ageStr)
        if age < 3:
            print("Your ticket is free.")
        elif age > 3 and age < 12:
            print("Ticket is $10")
        else:
            print("Ticket is $15")
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Using continue.
Note: this is bad as you specify and check for "quit" twice in the code and the control flow is overly complicated.

```
prompt = "\nPlease enter your age to see the price for a ticket. \nEnter 'quit' when done: "

age = ""

while age != "quit":
    age = input(prompt)
    if age == "quit":
        continue

    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("Your ticket is free.")
    elif age > 3 and age < 12:
        print("Ticket is $10")
    else:
        print("Ticket is $15")
```

Comment: The assignment was to not use 'break' or a variable as a flag. I have to use a conditional test in the 'while' statement. I dont know if its a trick question and not possible or?

Comment: what about continue or an exception? Otherwise I dont see how it can work. I wish they would teach the language as its supposed to be used, rather than having these weird limitations that force you to write non idiomatic code.

Comment: Can i use continue to make it work? If yes, then how?

Comment: A few more options, they are not recommended for real use though. I'd be interested to find out what the actual answer your teacher had in mind was. if it was either of these latter two I'd be shocked.

Comment: Also note you have a bug. If you enter the age as 3, it will drop through to the else clause, as your first check is for less than 3 and your second check is for greater than 3. The consequence is that as 3 doesnt meet either criteria it triggers the else ($15 tickets for 3 year olds).

Comment: Many thanks good sir. I'll be sure to get back to you with the answer he had in mind. I personally think he is trying to see if we remember to keep our code simple and efficient. Also I think he wants to show us that there are multiple different ways to solve a problem, but that not all ways are efficient. Me myself have spend the last hour and a half to figure out, how to solve it without using 'break'.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    age = input("\nPlease enter your age to see the price for a ticket. \n Enter 'quit' when done: '"
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    # continue with the rest of your code
```

Just check to see if the input is 'quit', if so, break out of the infinite loop.